# Check if there is an instance of a class in a list in python

Tags: python

If I have the following code

```
class Person:
    pass
me = Person()

people = ['john','doe',me]
```

What is the best way to check if there is an instance of Person in the list people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check that using `isinstance` like,

```
>>> class Person:
...   pass
...
>>> me = Person()
>>> people = ['john','doe',me]
>>> any(isinstance(x, Person) for x in people)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a for loop

```
found=False
for element in people:
    if element == isinstance(element,Person):
        found = True
        break
print(found)
```